# understanding MSB LSB

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am working on converting a program that runs on a specific micro-controller and adapt it to run on the raspberry pi. I have successfully been able to pull values from the sensor I have been working with but now I have run into a problem and I think it is caused by a few lines of code I am having trouble understanding. I have read up on what they are but am still scratching my head. The code below I believe is supposed to modify the number that gets stored in the `X,Y,Z` variables however I don't think this is occurring in my current program. Also I had to change `byte` to an `INT` to get the program to compile with out errors. This is the unmodified code from the original code I have converted. Can someone tell me if this is even modifying the number in anyway?

```
void getGyroValues () {
  byte MSB, LSB;

  MSB = readI2C(0x29);
  LSB = readI2C(0x28);
  x = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);

  MSB = readI2C(0x2B);
  LSB = readI2C(0x2A);
  y = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);

  MSB = readI2C(0x2D);
  LSB = readI2C(0x2C);
  z = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);
}
```

Here is the original readI2C function:

```
int readI2C (byte regAddr) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
    Wire.write(regAddr);                // Register address to read
    Wire.endTransmission();             // Terminate request
    Wire.requestFrom(Addr, 1);          // Read a byte
    while(!Wire.available()) { };       // Wait for receipt
    return(Wire.read());                // Get result
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) is a 2-wire protocol used to talk to low-speed peripherals.

Your sensor should be connected over the I2C bus to your CPU. And you're reading 3 values from the sensor - x, y and z. The values for these are accessible from the sensor as `6 x 8-bit` registers.

```
x - Addresses 0x28, 0x29
y - Addresses 0x2A, 0x2B
z - Addresses 0x2C, 0x2D
```

`ReadI2C()` as the function name implies, reads a byte of data from a given address from your sensor and returns the data being read. The code in `ReadI2C()` is dependent on how your device's I2C controller is setup.

A byte is 8-bits of data. The MSB (`Most-Significant-Byte`) and LSB(`Least-Significant-Byte`) denote 8-bits each read over `I2C`.
It looks like you're interested in a 16-bit data (for x, y and z). To construct the 16-bit data from the 2 pieces of 8-bit data, you shift the `MSB` by 8-bits to the left and then perform a logical-OR operation with the `LSB`.

For example:

> Let us assume: MSB = 0x45 LSB = 0x89
>
> MSB << 8 = 0x4500
>
> (MSB << 8) | LSB = 0x4589

Look at my comments inline as well:

```
void getGyroValues () {
  byte MSB, LSB;

  MSB = readI2C(0x29);
  LSB = readI2C(0x28);
  // Shift the value in MSB left by 8 bits and OR with the 8-bits of LSB
  // And store this result in x
  x = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);

  MSB = readI2C(0x2B);
  LSB = readI2C(0x2A);
  // Do the same as above, but store the value in y
  y = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);

  MSB = readI2C(0x2D);
  LSB = readI2C(0x2C);
  // Do the same as above, but store the value in z
  z = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);
}
```

Comment: @Yamaha32088 - I've edited my answer. Let me know if it answers all the questions you have or if you need more specific details.